# Calculation returning 0.0

Tags: java

I'm having some issues with an assignment for my Java class. My calculation of numCredits * creditFee + addFee is not processing; it continues to return 0.0

The assignment:

[image: Assignment Screenshot]

(Note, I have not yet added the additional parts of the assignment, the adding and subtracting of 3 credit hours to RegistrationTester. I will add those once I figure out this problem.)

Here is a look at my code:

```
public class Registration {
    //attributes
private String firstName = ""; 
private String lastName = "";
private double numCredits = 0;
private double addFee = 0;
private double creditFee = 70;
public double balance = 0;

//constructor
public Registration(String firstName, String lastName, double numCredits, double addFee){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.numCredits = numCredits;
    this.addFee = addFee;
}

public Registration(){} //
 public void balance(double balance){
   System.out.println(numCredits * creditFee + addFee);
 }
   public void addCredit(double addCredit){
   if (this.balance > 0) {
   this.balance = balance + addCredit * creditFee;
   }
   }
   
   public void subCredit(double subCredit){
   if (this.balance > 0){
   this.balance = balance - (subCredit * creditFee);
   }
   }
//setters
public void setFirstName(String fname){
    this.firstName = fname;
}
public void setLastName(String lname){
    this.lastName = lname;
}
public void setNumCredits(double credits){
    this.numCredits = credits;
   }
   public void setAddFee(double fee){
   this.addFee = fee;
   }
   public void setcreditFee(double creditFee){
   this.creditFee = 70;
   }
   public void setBalance(double balance){
   this.balance = balance;
   }
   
    //getters
   
   public String getFirstName(){
   return this.firstName;
   }
   public String getLastName(){
       return this.lastName;
   }
   public double getNumCredits(){
   return this.numCredits;
   }
   public double getAddFee(){
   return this.addFee;
   }
   public double getCreditFee(){
   return this.creditFee;
   }
  public double getBalance(){
      return this.balance;
  }
   
}
```

and

```
public class RegistrationTester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Registration student1 = new Registration ("m", "w", 15, 60);
    Registration student2 = new Registration ("d", "y", 12, 45);
    
    //display students and their current stats
    
    System.out.printf("%s %s:%n Current Credit Hours: %f%n Additional Fees: $%.2f%n"
            + "Current balance due: $ %.2f%n", 
            student1.getFirstName(),student1.getLastName(), student1.getNumCredits(), student1.getAddFee(),
            student1.getBalance());
    System.out.printf("%s %s:%n Current Credit Hours: %f%n Additional Fees: $%.2f%n"
            + "Current balance due: $ %.2f%n", 
            student2.getFirstName(), student2.getLastName(), student2.getNumCredits(), student2.getAddFee(),
            student2.getBalance());        
        
}
}
```

Comment: Remove `if (this.balance > 0) {` from `addCredit()`, otherwise there’s no possibility of `balance` ever increasing from zero, which is its starting value.

Comment: "My calculation of numCredits * creditFee + addFee is not processing" In your own words, why do you think it "should process", and what do you think the result should be? Trace through the logic from beginning to end, and explain exactly what you expect to happen within each function. Then look at the code you have there, and try to relate what the code says will happen to what you actually want to happen.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you intend the `balance` method to work. Why does it accept a parameter that is also named `balance`? What value will you provide there, and what does it have to do with the working of the method? Why does the calculation `numCredits * creditFee + addFee` tell you anything relevant here - what is the *underlying problem you are trying to solve*? What is the underlying *concept you are trying to model*?

Comment: I agree, but I think it is better for beginners to be talked through the steps of debugging before they are given the answers.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hm. Yes - I do agree, although sometimes the "talking through" really does happen in the answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I felt as though the math was correct but I knew *something* was wrong since it was defaulting to just 0.0 even though my program would essentially run with no error; just incorrect balance total. I take your input to heart! thank you for it. I was at the point of frustration since I have been working/editing the code for hours but I just couldn't see what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Properly setting balance**

The balance always returns `0.0` because you never set the balance in your method.

I believe your balance method should be:

```
 public void balance(double balance){
   this.balance=(numCredits * creditFee + addFee);
 }
```

**Method 2: Returning balance**

You can replace `student1.getBalance()` in RegistrationTest.java with `student1.balance()` that returns a double.

RegistrationTest should be:

```
System.out.printf("%s %s:%n Current Credit Hours: %f%n Additional Fees: $%.2f%n"
        + "Current balance due: $ %.2f%n", 
        student1.getFirstName(),student1.getLastName(), student1.getNumCredits(), student1.getAddFee(),
        student1.balance());
```

And the method *balance()* should be:

```
 public double balance(){
   return (numCredits * creditFee + addFee);
 }
```

With these changes it outputs:

```
Mihail Dichev:
 Current Credit Hours: 15.000000
 Additional Fees: $60.00
Current balance due: $ 1110.00
Dene Logan:
 Current Credit Hours: 12.000000
 Additional Fees: $45.00
Current balance due: $ 885.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! At one point I did have 
public void balance(double balance){
this.balance = numCredits * creditFee + addFee
sans the (). But I was also lacking the return statement. 

For some reason, in RegistrationTester the student1.balance() would not work but the student1.getBalance() would. I was getting an error stating that the method and type did not match. 

This will help me with the other two parts of my assignment as well.
Thank you very much.

Comment: "For some reason," You need to make things match up. If you called the method something in one place, you need to use that same name elsewhere, otherwise you aren't actually referring to it. If you want the method to return a particular *type* of value, then you need to a) *actually return* a value that *actually is* that type, **and** b) *explicitly declare* that the method returns that type.